# C converts file from x columns to x/2 cols with second half of file on next line using fprintf string %.*s

Tags: c, string, printf

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
/*  return 0;  */
FILE *in, *out;
char text_buffer[80];
char text_buffer2[80];
puts ("This program converts file from 16 columns to 8 cols with second half of file on next line");
    printf ("Input File:");
    gets (text_buffer);
    sscanf (text_buffer, "%79s", text_buffer2);
    if ((in = fopen (text_buffer2, "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        puts ("Can't open input file!");
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
        puts (text_buffer2);
    printf ("Output File:");
    gets (text_buffer);
    sscanf (text_buffer, "%79s", text_buffer2);
    if ((out = fopen (text_buffer2, "wt")) == NULL)
    {
        puts ("Can't open output file!");
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    printf ("Working...");
        puts ("A");
        puts (text_buffer2);
    char buffer[17];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL) {
        // Copy first 32 characters to the output file
        fprintf(out, "%.*s\n", 8, buffer);

        // Copy characters 32 to 64 to the second line in the output file
        fprintf(out, "%.*s\n", 8, buffer + 8);
    }  
// Close input and output file in and out 
fclose(in);
fclose(out);
printf("Conversion completed successfully.\n");
return 0;
}
```

My input file is

```
    123456789ABCDEF0
    AAABBBCCCDDDEEFF
    123456789ABCDEF0
```

outfile should be

```
    12345678
    9ABCDEF0
    AAABBBCC
    CDDDEEFF
    12345678
    9ABCDEF0
```

But I get output with 3 and 4 line blank and 5 line a repeat of line 2.
This error repeats for every second line written.
Can someone find the error?

It has to be on 8, buffer + 8) line??
I changed while loop using strncpy and that worked.

Comment: I tried to add actual output, but kept getting flagged for too much code so I had to cut something

Comment: A very simple option is to process one character at a time and simply ignore the newline character(s). Possibly even ignore all whitespace, depending on your needs. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/snK7f1veT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
char buffer[17];
```

Insufficient space to store what you intend when "reading in one full line."

Your input is actually:

```
//           1      1  << Note: 17 characters per line
//  12345678901234567
    123456789ABCDEF0$ // where '$' represents '\n'
    AAABBBCCCDDDEEFF$
    123456789ABCDEF0$
```

As such, the receiving buffer should be *oversized*, allowing `fgets()` to load the intended 16 characters, the end-of-line character and also have space to put a trailing `'\0'` on the buffer.

Simple fix:

```
char buffer[ 64 ]; // abundant room!
```

Much more could be said about **NOT** using `gets()` for input (risking overflow), and validating that, yes, the input string contains the expected 8+8 characters. This is for another day.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for this input.  My actual file has 64 characters and I had used buffer[65] with same problem.  I assume I should have used buffer[100}?

Comment: The size of the input buffer _should_ accommodate, at a minimum, the expected length of incoming strings (include LF or CRLF) and the trailing `'\0'` that `fgets()` appends... With (likely) 8Mb of stack, there's no reason to _scrimp_ on the buffer size. Yes, `100`, or `128` (power of 2), or even `256`. You've already paid for the memory. May as well use it!

Comment: would you recommend a better algorithm for this kind of file manipulation?  Just a sentence, not code

Comment: As @paddy has shown, using _stdin_ and _stdout_ instead of prompting for filenames (or using `argv[]`) would mean that your program could be used as a "_filter_" Eg. `yourprog < widefile.txt > narrowfile.txt` or `cat infile | yourprog | more` ("more" is a "pagenation" utility)... You should check that the input line is at least "length / 2" characters long before presuming there's a _part two_ to output... Glad it's working for you...

Comment: PS: a single TAB expands to 1 to 8 (typically) characters of output... You might want to try accommodating this when not splitting lines on a multiple of 8...